# Haskell QuickCheck minimal counter example

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Consider the following tests for the [distributivity law between reverse and ++](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/pbv/an-introduction-to-quickcheck-testing),

```
import Test.QuickCheck

test :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
test xs ys = reverse (xs ++ ys) == reverse xs ++ reverse ys

test2 :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
test2 xs ys = reverse (xs ++ ys) == reverse xs ++ reverse ys
```

Note for lists of `Int` that

```
*Main> quickCheck test
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 5 tests and 3 shrinks):    
[1]
[0]
```

However the test for lists of equatable items,

```
*Main> quickCheck test2
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

What makes the second test pass ?

**Update** On compiling with `main = quickCheck test2`, the subsequent error on ambiguous type variable hints the problem (as already depicted in answers),

```
No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of `test2'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you actually evaluate `test2`, GHCi has to pick a type `a` to use. Without more information, GHCi's extended default rules make it default to `()`, for which the law is true.

Answer (score 13):

```
> verboseCheck test2 

Passed:
[]
[]
Passed:
[]
[]
Passed:
[(),()]
[()]
Passed:
[(),(),()]
[()]
Passed:
[()]
[(),(),(),()]
...
```

The polymorphic parameter defaults to `()`, and of course all such values are equal.